# generating set for multiplicative group of integers modulo $2^k-1$

Tags: group-theory

Is there an easy way to construct a generating set ${2,g_2,g_3,g_4,...}$ for the group $(\mathbb{Z}/(2^k-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$ (multiplicative group of integers modulo $2^k-1$)? Is the minimum number elements in the generating set bounded?

[OEIS A046072](https://oeis.org/A046072) lists a minimum number of generators $a(n)$ for $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ and it seems to be a very small number with occasional spikes (the only number less than 10000 with $a(n) = 6$ is $n=9240$) but nothing to say that you can't find $n$ that requires any given number of elements in a generating set.

Answer (score 1):

Write $n$ as a product of prime numbers.  For example, $9240=2^3.3.5.7.11$
Each element $m$ of the group can be represented as a vector $(a,b,c,d,e)$ where $a=m\pmod8$ is in $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times$; $b=m\pmod3$ is in $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^\times$ and so on for $m\pmod5$, $m\pmod7$ and $m\pmod{11}$.
And vice versa: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, each vector has an $m$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/9240\mathbb{Z})^\times$.
$(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times$ needs two generators $3$ and $5$, but the other groups only need one each.
The six generators for $(\mathbb{Z}/9280\mathbb{Z})^\times$ are, in vector form,
$$(3,1,1,1,1)\\(5,1,1,1,1)\\(1,2,1,1,1)\\(1,1,2,1,1)\\(1,1,1,3,1)\\(1,1,1,1,2)$$

Comment: Some generators can be merged. You factorized it but you didn't state the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/9240\mathbb{Z})^\times$ which is a direct product of cyclic groups and has a minimum number of generators